# Images are not shown in the post editor

Tags: block-editor, post-editor

I created my posts with lots of images jut fine. If I open the editor after a while  the images are not shown anymore. It's just showing a placeholder with the image title. If I open the image gallery and hit update, the image reappears.

Any ideas whats wrong?

[image]

Comment: Is it just broken in the editor or is it broken on the site too? Can you look at the URL it's trying to load for a broken image - is there anything obviously wrong with it? Can you compare it to the correct URL after a refresh? Do you have any plugins that do background image resizing, or offloading to a CDN, or something like that?

Comment: Hey! I suggest you to activate the debugging and look in `debug.log` and inspect the console. Do you see any particular error?